# Dealing with collinearity

Tags: regression, correlation, multicollinearity

I have a variable called Instagram reach, which represents the number of people who viewed a post, and engagement is the number of unique individuals who interacted with that post. We know that engagement is influenced by reach, so there is a very high collinearity between these variables. I would like a method that seeks to "remove" the effect of reach on engagement.

Comment: It would help if you explain how are you planning to analyze the data. It seems you have one dependent and one independent variable. In that case, the concept of multicollinearity is redundant.

Comment: As noted by the comment by DevD, the concept of multicollinearity doesn't really apply in your case. This would only be an issue if you had multiple predictors.