# Dealing with covariance

Tags: confidence-interval, covariance, factor-analysis

Within my dataset, I employ a variable termed "Instagram reach," quantifying the audience size exposed to a particular post. Simultaneously, "engagement" denotes the count of distinct individuals actively interacting with said post. The established understanding is that engagement is intricately connected to reach, substantiated by a notably high covariance between these variables. To discern and disentangle the influence of reach on engagement, I am keen on employing a methodology capable of effectively "neutralizing" this impact. My intention is to undertake a comprehensive Factor Analysis, guided by the hypothesis of segregating distinct factors—one specifically dedicated to encapsulating the essence of reach and another isolating the contributing elements related to engagement.

Comment: What is your question?  If you're attempting to clarify your [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/641626/dealing-with-collinearity), then please return to that thread and edit it.